# Npgsql Pooled Connection Reset With Redshift

Tags: .net, amazon-redshift, npgsql

In the npgsql docs (https://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html?q=DISCARD%20ALL), it says that:-

Connection reset happens via the PostgreSQL DISCARD ALL command

I don't think Redshift has this command so what happens under the covers for a Redshift connection?

Does it simply not work and the pooled connection doesn't get its state reset?

Does it do something else, maybe Redshift-specific?

(I have run with verbose logging and have not seen any logs talking about connection state failing to be reset or errors like "DISCARD statement not found" or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, for Redshift Npgsql does not reset the state, since there's no way to do that.

Comment: ah ok so I wouldn't be able to do anything myself to clear the state once i have the new open connection? if not then would the best option be to turn off pooling for redshift?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what Redshift supports for resetting connection state - you'd have to research that. But this shouldn't at all be a blocker for using pooling: connection state isn't that common anyway, you just need to be aware of not doing certain things. For example, if you change any connection parameter with SET, that will leak; but as long as you don't do this (and some other things), it should be a problem.

Comment: i guess my issue is that i don't quite understand the difference between connections and sessions when it comes to redshift - i was expecting connections to be pooled but to get a new session for every use of a connection from the pool (as covered by the scope of my using statement). as part of this new session, ...

Comment: i was expecting no existing uncommitted transactions or temp tables hanging over from previous sessions that may have had issues, but this was not the case during a few incidents i had recently - the state was carried over to the new use of the connection and caused a spiral of errors which consumed all available redshift connections :(

Comment: but thankfully with your reply about no resetting of the state, i at least understand what is happening so i can put something in place to handle any existing "stuff" in a connection drawn from the pool, many thanks shay :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Npgsql does roll back uncommitted transactions, regardless of the state reset. Re temp tables, there's no way for Npgsql to know about them (it doesn't parse your SQL). There may be some specific resets available even in Redshift which we could send, but nobody has looked into it (and I haven't had an available Redshift instance to experiment with).